# When specifying who can review a PR, how do we specify a different email address?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

The team I'm on at work is working at developing competence at branching strategies using Git. We've previously used TFVC but want to move to Git. At this point it's our intention to use Azure DevOps Services for both source control and the build/release using Azure Pipelines.

I've been reading up on branching strategies using Git. I came across the [Adopt a Git Branching Strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/git-branching-guidance?view=azure-devops) page and other related pages. Incredibly valuable information there! However, I do have one important question which is a consequence of our environment. All our licenses to things like Microsoft 365, Visual Studio, MSDN licensing, etc., is tied to an email address ending in *nmhealth.org*. However, for reasons which I'm not privy to, that's not actually our work email addresses. My work email address is on domain *state.nm.us*. In essence, although all our licensing is through *nmhealth.org*, there is no email inbox there. All email has to go through everyone's *state.nm.us* email. But if we set up things like who's going to review PRs, how do we do that in Azure DevOps Pipelines? Everyone's account in Azure Pipelines is associated with their *nmhealth.org*. At this point when we make up policies in Azure Pipelines concerning PRs, such as reviewers, no one will ever get an email informing them that they should review a new PR.

[image]

Comment: Note that PRs (pull requests) are not a *Git* feature, and are implemented somewhat differently on each hosting site. Presumably you're interested in how Azure DevOps implements them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People can set an alternate email address in their profile.

[image]

If your account is linked to AAD, that email should automatically flow from Azure Active Directory, if the contact email is configured there.

You can also edit your notification subscription settings and set an alternate email address for a specific notification class:

[image]

This is only possible for non-default subscriptions. So you may need to disable a global notification and create a personal notification subscription in order to set the custom email address.

You can recognize the global subscriptions by the  icon.

Comment: I did not know about this, thank you @jessehouwing! This is what we'll all have to do, then.

Comment: I found that page, but my options don't look anything like what you've got. I don't think I can post a picture to a Stack Overflow comment, so I'll add it to an answer.

Comment: When you create  new subscription, does that work? What permission level do you have? I am account owner...

Comment: Ahhh, some of these have a  icon, that means they are default subscriptions, you can't edit those to that level, thy are enabled at the org level. You can turn these off though and replicate their functionality with your own version.

Answer (score 1):

Click on user settings in the top right of ADO next to you picture.

Click on Profile

Set your preferred contact email.

If you want more granularity or want to send email to a DL when a PR is created and assigned to a specific group or user for review you can go to notifications and create a new subscription.

This is briefly described in the MS doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/about-notifications?view=azure-devops